# The c# windows app with Access database (accdb) doesn't work on other computers after installation

Tags: c#, database, database-connection, oledbconnection

I want to insert a text in my Access database (accdb) in C#-windows application project. The "accdb" . 
It works correctly on my computer ONLY if i run the exe file which situated in my project source folder but the problem is that when i build a setup file and installed it and run the software, it opens but when i click on the insert button, it couldn't work. The problem is with the database (location/access) but i dont't know how can i solve it. 
Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

The error is: Unhandled exception has occurred in your application. ... "Unhandled exception has occurred in your application. If you click Continue, the application will ignore this error and attempt to continue. If you click Quit, the application will close immediately.
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80004005): Operation muss eine aktualisierbare Abfrage verwenden.
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, Object& executeResult)

[image]
[image]

Here is my code:

```
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static string GetDBConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            string dbExecPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "Test11.accdb");
            return $"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={ dbExecPath }";
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }

   OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(GetDBConnection());
   OleDbCommand cmd;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("insert into[Table](name, code) VALUES(@name, @code)", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", textBox1.Text);
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@code", textBox2.Text);

            con.Open();

            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("An Item has been successfully added", "Caption", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

        int i = 0;
        i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (i > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Inserted");
            DisplayData();
        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Not Inserted");
        }
        con.Close();
        ///////
    }
```

Comment: Is it the location or a permission problem ? It's always good to write the error message to we can understand more.

Comment: @Kaj. Thanks for the reply. i added the error just right now to my main question

Comment: @rene: ok, Thanks. i removed try catch but i still have the same problem. and as a note if i run it from visual studio and insert sth into my database, it inserts but if i close it and run it a gain, there is nothing in data base (it disappeared) so it means sth in my connection with database has problem but i don't know what is it

Comment: @rene But it works correctly ONLY if i run the exe file from my computer.(Then i can insert data, close the software and data saved in database correctly)

Comment: Is that Test11.accdb read-only where it doesn't work? Maybe on a read-only disk/network share? Does Table only have those two columns? Table is a Table, right? Not a query? That other computer does have the Access Database Engine installed, right?

Comment: @rene : No, it is not read only. the table has Id column plus two empty columns.

Comment: Add a screenshot of your table designer. Is id autonumber? Is it required?

Comment: is the access engine installed in the target machine ?

Comment: Do all the machines have office 2007 installed (version 12.0)?  The ACE driver comes with Microsoft Office and the ACE version need to match the version of of Office installed.

Comment: @rene i added the screenshot. yeah id is autonumber

Comment: @ErwinDraconis No, i want to try it now. i will update you soon if it works...Thanks

Comment: @jdweng Yeah, they have the same office version

Comment: @ErwinDraconis No the problem didn't solve. actually when i install this app even in my computer, i can not insert anything to it.
It works ONLY if i double click on exe file in my source project folder.
I huess there is sth wrong with accessing to database in my code that prevent working after installation

Comment: Well the DataSource part in your connection string changes with the location of your .exe as you use `Assembly.getExecutingAssembly().Location` Make sure the .accdb ist still accessible under that path after you move your .exe.

Comment: then you have somethin wrong with the path of your DB, did you check what the dbExecPath  referes to when its installed in other location ? put a message box or log it in txt file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you use `Assembly.getExecutingAssembly().Location` to specify the location of you .accdb-file. As soon as you change the location of your executable (.exe) the value that `Assembly.getExecutingAssembly().Location` returns changes ([See MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.getexecutingassembly?view=netframework-4.8)). So you need to make sure your executable and your .accdb-file are always in the same folder. Otherwise a connection to your Access database cannot be established.

You could add a message box that shows the path your program expects the database to be located. Afterwards you can check whether your database really is located in the right directory.

Comment: Thanks. please see the new screenshot that i uploaded.
i put a button to show the database location. as you see in pic1 the path is correct.
The exe file is also located beside it. But still when i click on the insert button i see the same error (pic2). Why?
Thanks

Comment: your DB is located in program file, one reason is that the program does not have rights to read-write in this location, try putting it in desktop

Comment: @ErwinDraconis Thanks a lot. it works on desktop, could you pls also tell how can i get permission to it to install it on program file?
I added this code but i think it is not correct!: Thanks.
            FileIOPermission f2 = new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Read, Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "Test11.accdb"));
            f2.AddPathList(FileIOPermissionAccess.Write | FileIOPermissionAccess.Read, Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "Test11.accdb"));